# Proving $o(g^r) = n / \gcd(n,r) $?

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory

Let $G$ be a group, and let $g \in G$ be an element of order $n \in \mathbb{N} \setminus \{0\}$. Prove that for all $r \in \mathbb{Z}$ we have $$ o(g^r) = \frac{ n}{\gcd(n,r)} $$ where $o(g^r)$ means the order of $g^r$ in $G$.

**Attempt at proof:** Let $r \in \mathbb{Z}$ be arbitrary. Let $m \geq 1$ be a positive integer. Then $(g^r)^m = g^{rm} = e $ if and only if $n \mid rm $ since $n$ is the smallest positive integer such that $g^n= e$. Since $n$ divides $rm$, there exists a $q \in \mathbb{Z}$ such that $nq = rm$. So $ m = nq / r$. I want now to conclude somehow that $$ nq = \operatorname{lcm}(n,r) $$ since we can then use the relation $$ \frac{n}{\gcd(n,r)} = \frac{\operatorname{lcm}(n,r)}{r} $$ and the assertion would follow. Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use $ o(g^r) $ to denote the given expression, and I prove that it is the order of $ g^r $.

First, we note the equality $ \gcd(a, b) \textrm{lcm}(a, b) = ab $. Now, we verify the claim. First, we check that $(g^r)^{o(g^r)} = 1 $:

$$ (g^r)^{o(g^r)} = g^{nr/\gcd(n, r)} = g^{\textrm{lcm}(n, r)} = 1 $$

as $ \textrm{lcm}(n, r) $ is a multiple of $ n $. On the other hand, assume that there is $ x < o(g^r) $ such that $ g^{rx} = 1 $, then $ n | rx $ so that $ rx $ is a common multiple of $ r $ and $ n $. By definition of the least common multiple, $ rx $ is then divisible by the lcm and $ x $ is divisible by $ \textrm{lcm}(n, r) / r = n/\gcd(n, r) = o(g^r) $, contradicting our assumption. Therefore, $ o(g^r) $ is indeed the order of $ g^r $.

Comment: Thanks. When you say $rx$ is divisible by the lcm, you mean $lcm(r,n)$ right?

Comment: Yes, of course.